# Rate limiting PHP function

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, throttling

I have a php function which gets called when someone visits `POST www.example.com/webhook`. However, the external service which I cannot control, sometimes calls this url twice in rapid succession, messing with my logic since the webhook persists stuff in the database which takes a few ms to complete.

In other words, when the second request comes in (which can not be ignored), the first request is likely not completed yet however I need this to be completed in the order it came in.

So I've created a little hack in Laravel which should "throttle" the execution with 5 seconds in between. It seems to work most of the time. However an error in my code or some other oversight, does not make this solution work everytime.

```
function myWebhook() {
    // Check if cache value (defaults to 0) and compare with current time.
    while(Cache::get('g2a_webhook_timestamp', 0) + 5 > Carbon::now()->timestamp) {
        // Postpone execution.
        sleep(1);
    }
    // Create a cache value (file storage) that stores the current 
    Cache::put('g2a_webhook_timestamp', Carbon::now()->timestamp, 1);
    // Execute rest of code ...
}
```

Anyone perhaps got a watertight solution for this issue?

Comment: i think database locking would be a better aproach

Comment: One time I was coding a site where many people could probably make transactions at the same time, but that couldn't be allowed. So I created a special table called `turns` in the transactions database and I created a turn for every session or user immediately after, so the code would execute once your turn was reached. I was controlling this with a while loop and sleep function too, so we agree on that. And the method to check the turn was getting the list ordered by `id` ASC and limited to 1 result. That would make it more efficient. If the session or user `id` matched, the loop was exited.

Comment: But _record locking_, otherwise known as _database locking_, is the best approach, definitely. [Read more...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking)

Comment: how does it relate to a database transaction? I'm looking for an easy implementation within Laravel

Answer (score 1):

You have essentially designed your own simplified queue system which is the right approach but you can make use of the native Laravel queue to have a more robust solution to your problem.

1. Define a job, e.g: `ProcessWebhook`
2. When a POST request is received to `/webhook` queue the job

The laravel queue worker will process one job at a time[1] in the order they're received, ensuring that no matter how many requests are received, they'll be processed one by one and in order.

The implementation of this would look something like this:

1. [Create a new Job](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#creating-jobs), e.g: `php artisan make:job ProcessWebhook`
2. Move your webhook processing code into the `handle` method of the job, e.g:

   ```
   public function __construct($data)
   {
       $this->data = $data;
   }

   public function handle()
   {
       Model::where('x', 'y')->update([
           'field' => $this->data->newValue
       ]);
   }
   ```
3. Modify your Webhook controller to dispatch a new job when a POST request is received, e.g:

   ```
   public function webhook(Request $request)
   {
       $data = $request->getContent();
       ProcessWebhook::dispatch($data);
   }
   ```
4. Start your queue worker, `php artisan queue:work`, which will run in the background processing jobs in the order they arrive, one at a time.

That's it, a maintainable solution to processing webhooks in order, one-by-one. You can read the [Queue documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues) to find out more about the functionality available, including retrying failed jobs which can be very useful.

[1] Laravel will process one job at a time *per worker*. You can add more workers to improve queue throughput for other use cases but in this situation you'd just want to use one worker.

Comment: ive actually have a similar setup in another app, however due to the limit of CRON, tasks are ran in increments of 1 minute, which does not improve user experience when you have to wait 1 minute for a webhook to be executed.

So in this other app i ended up with making a 1 minute task, effectively re-checking the queue every 5 seconds for a 1 minute period. After that the task would end and be called again using the CRON.

I will look into database transactions / record locking first because I think that may solve the problem more easily.

Comment: @Flame the Laravel queue worker is not ran as a cron job, it is ran as a background job (it is always running, waiting for new jobs), meaning the latency between a job being created and a job being processed can be as low as you like. A queue worker processes jobs as soon as they're added to the queue (as long as it's not already processing a job). You should take some time to read through the documentation as it's exactly the functionality you need. You're thinking about task scheduling which is different Laravel functionality.

Comment: my bad you're right, `php artisan queue:work` runs forever, however I had to make a mix with the task scheduler because I was on a shared hosting environment